# Can I create test using java in android studio as we create tag

Tags: java, android, android-studio, tags

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkADJ.jpg)

I face notification error any help to resolve it

Answer (score 1):

You need to write following code to get your red underlined line fixed:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent (MainActivity.this,NotificationView.class);
```

and for the next one you need to set `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this` like that:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0,notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```